# Opening a .txt file in Xcode using C and fopen( )

Tags: c, file, text-files

I can't seem to get a file to open in C.  What am I doing wrong?  The file is in the same directory as the .c file and I think I got all the syntax.  Here is a screenshot: [image]

The output says that the file pointer is NULL.

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50959508/how-to-use-relative-path-to-open-files-in-c-using-xcode) may help.

Answer (score 0):

For that to work, the "test.txt" has to be in the same directory as the compiled binary (which xcode may not be putting in the same directory as main.c - it may be in Products? I'm not so sure with xcode). Try giving the fully-qualified pathname to test.txt in the call to fopen.

Answer (score 0):

If `fopen`fails, fp is set to NULL and errno is set according. To see why, try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int
main( void )
{
  int status = EXIT_SUCCESS;
  FILE *fp = fopen(“test.txt”, “r”);
  if( fp == NULL )
  {
    fprintf( stderr, “Errno %d, Error %s, opening text.txt for reading.\n”, errno, strerror(errno));
    status = errno;
  }

  // Do something with fp...
  return(status);
}
```

To open the file from any directory, pass the file name in argv, check for arguments and use that parameter to main as the file name( pref. after copying to a dedicated variable).